# WCF:Cannot obtain metadata error

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, tcp

I have my service hosted on IIS7 with net.tcp as enabled protocol.When I browse the service from IIS I can see the service page and its tcp address but if I use that address with WCF test client or with any application as service reference I get this error in wcf client

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:808/MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl 
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, 
please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. 
For help enabling metadata publishing, 
 please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455
WS-Metadata Exchange Error 
URI: http://localhost:808//MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl
 Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
 'http:/localhost:808/MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl .
 There was no endpoint listening at
'http:/localhost:808/MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl that could accept the message. 
 This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, 
 if present, for more details.    
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.HTTP GET Error 
URI: http:/localhost:808/MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl    
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
```

I am surprised when I put net.tcp address in wcf client why the error is about http only

my service config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>


 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
 </system.web>

 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TcpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
     maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             closeTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" 
         receiveTimeout="10:00:00"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="true" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="10:00:00" />
    </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehaviour" 
      name="MyService.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBinding"
      name="EndPointTCP" contract="MyService.IMyService" isSystemEndpoint="false" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
   </services>
     <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyService.MyServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"  />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>

   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate"       
       />
     </system.webServer>

  </configuration>
```

Comment: if you trying to add service reference then httpGetEnabled should be true in your service behavior

Comment: @SanjayRabadiya Well,I dont think its required for tcp binding.As I dont want my service to be accessed on http protocol.

Comment: sory i assume service use http binding.

Comment: specify full address like 'net.tcp://localhost:8889/MyService' for 'EndPointTCP' endpoint..

Comment: I figured out the root cause as there was some problem for activating WCF non http activation from windows features ,it always give error like Operation can not be completed.I am able to run my service on other machine but still want to know what could be the possible reason for the error for WCF non http activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the root cause as there was some problem for activating WCF non http activation from windows features ,it always give error like Operation can not be completed.I am able to run my service on other machine but still want to know what could be the possible reason for the error for WCF non http activation.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a netTcp Binding, you cannot add it in wcf test client and test it. To use in WCF test client, you need to expose the service with Http as well (i.e., with both Http and NetTcp binding). then you can browse the metadata and use it in wcf test client using Http. expose the service to client using NetTcp binding. Hope I have answered your question.

Note: in IIS under the website where you hosted, go to advance settings and mention the allowed bindings as "Http,NetTcp".

Comment: :"Since it is a netTcp Binding, you cannot add it in wcf test client and test it?"..Its possible,Iam successfully doing it and I have also set the enabled protocols in IIS for http and net.tcp I figured out the root cause as there was some problem for activating WCF non http activation from windows features ,it always give error like Operation can not be completed.I am able to run my service on other machine but still want to know what could be the possible reason for the error for WCF non http activation

Comment: What is the .Net framework version and OS you are using ? as there is a known bug from microsoft check the link here [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/455497/installation-of-net-framework-3-5-1-features-wcf-activation-http-activation-fails-with-error-0x80070643-when-net-4-beta-1-is-installed)